# When I try to install gulp, these errors come up and I cant figure out how to fix them

Tags: gulp

Im trying to install Gulp and these warnings come up but I've looked around and followed steps and still doenst fix this. Im in admin mode and nothing seems to work.

npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.1: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
npm WARN deprecated chokidar@2.1.8: Chokidar 2 does not receive security updates since 2019. Upgrade to chokidar 3 with 15x fewer dependencies
npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated

Im in admin mode and I went to Github for answers and nothing helped.